# How to slide in divs and load more on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to code the same animation effect as you can see on [this](https://undsgn.com/uncode/homepages/portfolio-metro/) website. I would like to fill my bootstrap grid with divs with smooth animation (slide in up) from left to right. [Here](https://youtu.be/3uppDyI2PrA) is a demo of what I've achieved so far. It is loaded chaotically, without any order and without animation. What should I do to load those divs in the same way as it happens on the website I mentioned above? Here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<div class="row" id="secondRow" style="background-color: black">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div1"> <img src="images/bg1.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div2"> <img src="images/bg2.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div3"> <img src="images/bg3.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div4"> <img src="images/bg4.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div5"> <img src="images/bg5.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div6"> <img src="images/bg6.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div7"> <img src="images/bg6.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div8"> <img src="images/bg6.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp" id="div9"> <img src="images/bg6.jpeg" alt="whatever"> </div>
    </div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
var showAll = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8", "div9"];
var web = ["div2", "div3", "div4"];
var adv = ["div2", "div5", "div6", "div7"];


function showHide(array) {
    if(document.getElementById) {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
            $(divs[i]).fadeOut("slow");
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j = j + 1) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(array[j]);
            if(array.length % 3 == 0) {
                document.getElementById(array[j]).className = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 hideable animated slideInUp";
            } else if(array.length % 4 == 0) {
                document.getElementById(array[j]).className = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 hideable animated slideInUp";
            }
            var divid = document.getElementById(array[j]);
            $(divid).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe the website you're referring to is based on [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). You could also check [this link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/) that provides multiple loading effects.